# Apply touch event to EVERY click event with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, dom-events, user-experience

Most events on websites are click events. However, the 300ms delay on mobile browsers for initiating click events is obviously undesirable: https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons?hl=de-DE

After reading the above post, I started to wonder if I could implement some kind of globally applicable code that would call a touch event each time a clickable button, link, etc was touched/clicked. The goal is to eliminate this 300ms delay to make the website feel more like a native app.

This code snippet would seem hugely valuable from a UI/UX perspective so just wondering people's thoughts on this or solutions they've come up with.

Answer (score 2):

That article says that `click` happens 300ms after `touchend`, so you'd want to do the reverse of what you asked:

```
$(document).bind('touchend', function(e) {
    $(e.target).trigger('click');
});
```

This would trigger a click event from the target of any touch event that bubbles up to the document level. It's not a particularly performant solution, but as a sledgehammer approach it ought to do the job.

Comment: hi @Mathletics, thanks for this, i need to figure out of your code is actually faster than just the `click()` alone. Have any suggestions for measuring performance?